# Reliable String interpolation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the best way to ensure that a model exists before doing string interpolation? I have a variable `user`, and I need to see what the `user`'s major is. A table in between named `user_attributes` has the user's info.

```
#{user.user_attribute.major.name}
```

The user may not have specified a major yet, in which case they wouldn't have a major model instance yet. So when I try and get the name of the major, I would get an "undefined method on nil class type" error. Any advice on how to safely do this?

Comment: [Demeter: It’s not just a good idea. It’s the law.](http://devblog.avdi.org/2011/07/05/demeter-its-not-just-a-good-idea-its-the-law/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could avoid `try` and add a method to your model or decorator..

```
def major_name
  user_attribute.major && user_attribute.major.name
end
```

OR

```
def major_name
  user_attribute.major.name if user_attribute.major?
end
```

Check: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28610/handling-nil-trying-to-avoid-try

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I went with. I like the idea of doing the logic in the model instead of the view so thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `try` method:

```
# if model is present
{user.user_attribute.major.try(:name)} # => "<MAJOR_NAME>"

# if model is NOT present
{user.user_attribute.major.try(:name)} # => ""
```

You can read more about [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [lonely operator](http://ruby-operators.herokuapp.com/#/lonely). It is like `try`, but slightly less functional (which doesn't matter in your case).

```
user.user_attribute.major&.name
```

Comment: @Leito: yes, forgot to mention, thanks :) And you mean "2.3+"

Comment: Hahaha, you are only future proofing your answer. 2.3 is the latest and we don't know if this is sticking in future versions, but I don't see it going anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This might well be the 'worst' answer to ruby puritans, but it works for me in some scenarios:

```
"#{user.user_attribute.major.name rescue nil}"
```

Comment: It's not about being a ruby puritan or not, it's simply not  good solution.

Comment: @Leito - why is it not a good solution? If all I want is the string if present, or a blank string if major is not  present, then this is a reasonable solution. In my scenario, I construct a complex string by interpolating various model methods, some of which may not be present. I use this and it works.

Comment: Is a misuse of exceptions (exceptional nature). You shouldn't expect one or use it as a conditional. There is also a performance hit, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/15397057/637094 for more details. I'm not arguing it works, I know it does and it's a solution, but simply not a good one.

Comment: Actually, I think it is the only good solution if we want to show something when the data not found (like "Unknown"), but correct me if I am wrong.